# 404 response when calling external web service from amazon ec2

Tags: web-services, amazon-ec2, httpresponse

When I call an external web service from Amazon EC2 server I get a 404 response for the request. When I call the same web service locally it works fine. Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible that the owner of the service has been seeing too much abuse from Amazon's IP range and that they have blocked access to the API from EC2. Normally however I would expect them to send back an Access Denied rather than a 404 Not Found.

Comment: Thanks.. there is any configuration in Amazon EC2 server console which blocks the access to other server APIs, I think there is no outbound filtering in amazon EC2

Comment: I'm not saying that EC2 or Amazon is limiting it, rather the API you are calling is not available from the IP address space that Amazon has for their EC2 instances.

Comment: thanks I am able to resolve it, the API server blocked all requests now we filtered properly